# Is it possible to make a bottom sheet appear from top instead of bottom in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to open a bottom sheet on tapping floating action button from top side instead of bottom. Is there any way to do that? Or is there any other widget that can be used for my purpose instead of bottomsheet ?

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
  floatingActionButton: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 235),
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print('float clicked');
        showBottomSheet(context);
      },
      tooltip: 'Add New ToDo',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ),

Future<void> showBottomSheet(BuildContext ctx) async {
showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 211, 230),
    isDismissible: true,
    context: ctx,
    builder: (ctx1) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180),
              ),
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Add New Task',
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Add'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: may help https://pub.dev/packages/top_modal_sheet

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `isScrollControlled: true,` to showModalBottomSheet.
2. Wrap your container inside builder of modalbottomsheet inside

   ```dart
    const FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 1.0,
        child: Container(...),
    ),
   ```

You will have the result you want.

Comment: Sir, I tried what you have suggested. Output was that the bottomSheet still surfaced from bottom side but this time it coverd the whole screen - https://prnt.sc/P8HOPfDKTRWD

I only want the bottomSheet with height 200 to surface from top side.

Comment: But that is not bottom sheet. Let me try it.